# Importar objetos de un json java

Tags: java, json

es la primera vez que pregunto.

Estoy intentando importar objetos desde un json a mi repositorio. Pero solamente me funciona cuando el json está "mal escrito", tal que así: (teams.json)

```
{
    "name": "EQUIPO1",
    "email": "EQUIPO1@EQUIPO1.com"
}
{
    "name": "EQUIPO2",
    "email": "EQUIPO2@EQUIPO2.com"
}
```

Y me gustaría que funcionase cuando el json es válido: (teams.json)

```
[
    {
    "name": "EQUIPO1",
    "email": "EQUIPO1@EQUIPO1.com"
    },
    {
    "name": "EQUIPO2",
    "email": "EQUIPO2@EQUIPO2.com",
    }
]
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./teams.json"))) {

        Iterator<Team> value = mapper.readValues(jsonFactory.createParser(br), Team.class);

        value.forEachRemaining(
                (tem) -> {
                    teamRepository.save((Team) tem);
                    });
    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @Javisap yo te recomendaría esta solución para facilitarte el recorrido del objecto, lo que debes haces es utilizar la clase TypeReference para inferir el tipo List:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./teams.json"))) {

    List<Team> value =  mapper.readValue(jsonFactory.createParser(br), new TypeReference<List<Team>>(){});

    value.forEach(team -> {
        teamRepository.save(team);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vaya error más tonto :facepalm:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./teams.json"))) {

        Iterator<Team[]> value = mapper.readValues(jsonFactory.createParser(br), Team[].class);

        value.forEachRemaining(
                (tem) -> {
                    for(Team aux: tem)
                    teamRepository.save(aux);
                    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `readValues()` es ideal para un escenario donde se necesitan procesar en streaming gran cantidad de elementos, pero donde cada elemento es independiente del anterior, sin embargo en tu caso no tiene mucho sentido utilizarlo si toda la información está en el primer y único elemento del fichero (me refiereo al array o List), yo usaría el típico `readValue()`, por ejemplo:

```
    final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    // Files.readString está disponible a partir de Java11, para versiones anteriores hay otras alternativas
    String json = Files.readString(Path.of("./teams.json"));

    TypeReference<List<Team>> type = new TypeReference<List<Team>>() {};
    List<Team> teams = MAPPER.readValue(json, type);
```

Otra opción, sin necesidad de usar `TypeReference` podría ser:

```
    List<Team> teams = List.of(MAPPER.readValue(json, Team[].class));
```